# How can I get Code 1, to act the same as Code 2?

Tags: html

http://testpageblog5678.blogspot.com/

My question, how come Code 1, when you click on it, it doesn't stay in place, but when you click on Code 2, it does stay in place. How can I get Code 1, to act the same as Code 2?

On Code 1, do you see how when you click on it, it all moves up, but Code 2, everything stays in place. How can I get Code 1 to act the same?

## Code 1

```html
<div style="width:596px" onclick="img=document.getElementById('myDiv8'); img.style.display='block';
    this.style.display='none'">

  <a style="cursor: pointer;display:inline-block; width: 596px; height: 74px; background-color:#000000; border: 5px solid #BF598E;"></a>
</div>

<div id="myDiv8" style="display: none;">

  <div style="background-color:green; color:white; width: 606px; height:84px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

## Code 2

```html
<div style="width:266px" onclick="myDiv=document.getElementById('myDiv'); myDiv.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">

  <a style="cursor: pointer;display:inline-block; width: 256px; height: 256px; background-color:red; Border: 5px solid #BF598E;">
  </a>
</div>

<div id="myDiv" style="display: none;">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M5VkVbK.png" style="width: 266px; height: 266px; " />
</div>
```

Comment: can't to see any `everything moves up` behavior

Comment: jukben Had the answer and I implemented it, so now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set these elements to block (because you are setting the hidden elements to block) not inline-block.

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;display:block; width: 256px; height: 256px; background-color:red; Border: 5px solid #BF598E;">
```

and

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;display:block; width: 596px; height: 74px; background-color:#000000; border: 5px solid #BF598E;"></a>
```

However it's not very nice nice code at all, but I suppose it's just for prove of concept.

Comment: Oh, that worked.  so, if there's an image involved, you put inline-block, if it's just purely html elements, you put block? http://testpageblog5678.blogspot.com/

Comment: How would you fix Code 1 or Code 2 for that matter to improve or fix them? https://jsfiddle.net/7wbgk3py/

Comment: Hi @assaassa. The basic issue here is that you setting the revealed element to block (img.style.display='block') and the current element is inline-block. The browser render block and inline-block differently.

Comment: How come both Block, and inline-block work the same? https://jsfiddle.net/7wbgk3py/8/ Is there a difference? And which one should it be? block or inline-block?

Comment: Can you help me with this please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901911/how-come-this-code-acts-differently-on-2-different-sites

Comment: I need your help with this please. How do I fix it so it stays in place and doesn't drop down? I added text to it, so now it's different. https://jsfiddle.net/7wbgk3py/11/

Comment: Hi, and what about do something like this @assaassa https://jsfiddle.net/bfunas9u/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myDiv8" style="display: none; padding-bottom: 5px;">
```

... or howmuch ever pixels you need to make it keep equal height.

Comment: On blogger, when you click on Code,1 everything moves up, but on Code 2, when you click on it, everything stays in place. http://testpageblog5678.blogspot.com/

Comment: @assaassa ... so you can add `padding-bottom: 5px;` to make it stay in place ;)